# Arduino USB Driver

Tags: c#, arduino, usb, driver

I want to make a program to interface with my Arduino through an USB port. I am already quite experienced with C# (which is the language I want to use), but I cannot find a way to install the Arduino USB driver without also installing the IDE. Can I download them somewhere? Or is there a better way to use USB (I do not need to upload any code to the board with the program)?

I know that there are a lot of tutorials on making the program, but they all seem to use the `SerialPort`class which I assume is not the actual USB port but just a serial port made by the driver.

In short: 
Q1: Where can I download the Arduino USB driver? 
Q2: If I can't, what is the best way to do communicate using USB (maybe another driver or library)?

(Please tell me if my question does not make sense, this is the first time I am doing something with USB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "original" Arduinos that have build-in chip for serial communication are using FTDI's FT232RL chip. Here's the driver for these: http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm

The most cheap clones of those Arduino boards (from eBay, Aliexpress, etc) are using the CH340 chip for serial communication. Driver for these: http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html

Comment: It is not true. Original Arduino doesn't use FT232. They use Atmega16U2 MCU specially programmed  to be discovered as virtual serial port. It is easy to find Arduino boards schematic.

Comment: Check the schematic of Arduino Nano and you will see that it's using the FT232RL chip:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoNano30Schematic.pdf

I don't know if all other boards also use it.

Comment: There are lots of Arduino boards and they mostly use MCU for Serial-to USB conversion. My opinion is that more correct answer for this question is something like: "Arduino detected as virual serial port in computer, doesn't matter what board or what driver is used". Your answer not covers all cases, but, yes, i agree that ft232 and ch340 are widely used in some boards, especially for custom arduino-compatible devices.

Comment: The original Arduino drivers are also in the IDE. There is a portable download available. So you can pick the drivers out.